# A confrontation between the columns

Tags: mysql

This is an excerpt from my table.

How to write the query to know if a person A has already included person B in the same comp

comp = the reference of the competition

```
+------------+--------+--------+------------------+-----+
| id         | comp   |id_name | name             | cl  |
+------------+--------+--------+------------------+-----+
| 4028000001 | 200000 | 445895 | Uhéliad Créiomin | 6e  |
| 4028000002 | 200000 | 445869 | Una II           | 2e  |
| 4028000003 | 200000 | 445872 | Ultracott        | 5e  |
| 4028000004 | 200000 | 449402 | Une Amie         | 3e  |
| 4028000005 | 200000 | 451463 | Uhelwad Creiomin | 1er |
| 4028000006 | 200000 | 449400 | Une de Boizel    | 7e  |
| 4028000007 | 200000 | 452511 | Uranie du Houx   | 8e  |
| 4028000008 | 200000 | 473479 | Urbain du Bois   | 4e  |
| 4068682801 | 202020 | 447452 | Trésor de Fercé  | 3e  |
| 4068682802 | 202020 | 455022 | Ski de Baune     | 4e  |
+------------+--------+--------+------------------+-----+
```

this query that I wrote but it was wrong

```
SELECT t.*
FROM   (
SELECT a.id_name, a.comp, a.name, a.cl 
      FROM pturf1.cachedate AS  a
      Left join pturf1.cachedate AS b on a.comp=b.comp
      WHERE a.comp = b.comp
      ) t 
WHERE t.idChe IN (SELECT idChe FROM pturf1.partant);
```

Comment: Is 4028000003 intrinsically more comprehensible than, say, 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want a self-join:

```
select distinct t1.id_name as id_name1, t2.id_name as id_name2
from mytable t1
inner join mytable t2 on t2.comp = t1.comp and t2.id_name > t1.id_name
```

This brings tuples of `id_name`s that participated the same `comp` at least once. The inequality condition ensures that no "mirror" records will show up in the resultset.

If you want to display the `comp` too, then:

```
select t1.id_name as id_name1, t2.id_name as id_name2, t1.comp
from mytable t1
inner join mytable t2 on t2.comp = t1.comp and t2.id_name > t1.id_name
```

Comment: ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 't.id_name' in 'IN/ALL/ANY subquery'

Comment: @Sobay: the queries I provided cannot raise that error (there are no subqueries to start with). Please run the queries exactly as provided.

Comment: this is how I write

Comment: 'SELECT t.*
FROM   (
select t1.id_name as id_name1, t2.id_name as id_name2, t1.comp
FROM pturf1.cachedate AS t1
inner join pturf1.cachedate t2 on t2.comp = t1.comp and t2.id_name > t1.id_name
      ) t 
WHERE t.id_name IN (SELECT id_name FROM pturf1.partant);'

Comment: @Sobay: and why don't you run the queries as I provided them?

Comment: I have a table with the names of the athletes

Comment: my base table is 4 million rows

Comment: I just have an intermediate table which corresponds to the rider of a competition

Comment: @Sobay: I can only answer based on the information you provided in the question, and that is not part of it. I would recommend testing the queries I provided. If you have different question, then you should ask it as *a new question*.

Comment: Thank you for your time